# How do extract string to some pattern using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having some phone number as string , i have split into in order to add some extension inside.What would be better solution rather than inserting at each index. Here is what i had tried.`1234567891346` is input output would be like `(123) - 456 - 7891 Ext - 346` .

```js
let phoneStr= '12345678912346';
     phoneStr.split("")
     let phoneNo =[];
     phoneNo[0]='(' ;
     phoneNo[1]=phoneStr[0] ;
     phoneNo[2]=phoneStr[1] ;
     phoneNo[3]=phoneStr[2] ;
     phoneNo[4]=')' ;
     phoneNo[5]=' - ' ;

     phoneNo[6]=phoneStr[3] ;
     phoneNo[7]=phoneStr[4] ;
     phoneNo[8]=phoneStr[5] ;
     phoneNo[9]=' - ' ;

     phoneNo[10]=phoneStr[6] ;
     phoneNo[11]=phoneStr[7] ;
     phoneNo[12]=phoneStr[8] ;
     phoneNo[13]=phoneStr[9] ;
     phoneNo[14]=' Ext - ' ;

     phoneNo[15]=phoneStr[10] ;
     phoneNo[15]=phoneStr[11] ;
     phoneNo[16]=phoneStr[12] ;
     phoneNo[17]=phoneStr[13] ;
     phoneNo[18]=phoneStr[14] ;
     console.log( phoneNo.toString().replace(/,/g , ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```js
let phoneStr= '12345678912346';
let formatted = '(' + phoneStr.slice(0,3) + ') - ' + phoneStr.slice(3,6) + ' - ' + phoneStr.slice(6,10) + ' Ext - ' + phoneStr.slice(10,15);
console.log(formatted);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let phoneNo = `(${phoneStr.slice(0,3)}) - ${phoneStr.slice(3,5)} - ${phoneStr.slice(5,10)} Ext - ${phoneStr.slice(10, 14)}`
```

Maybe you need babel

Comment: @yudong is better